# Tire + Will_Paginate not taking Tire.options

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, tire

I'm trying to integrate Tire into my site and I'm having difficulty with pagination. I've tried paginating the results outside of the context of Tire and will_paginate is working on that Array. However, when I try will_paginate within the context of Tire I'm having one large problem.

Will_Paginate will display the correct number of pages with consideration of :per_page but when I click on that page the results are not loaded, rather they are the same as on the first page. The page number is highlighted in the will_paginate navigation.

@results.inspect yields this:

```
    #<Tire::Search::Search:0x007f88ab9153d0 @indices=["deja-set-development"], @types=[],        @options={:load=>true, :page=>1, :per_page=>2}, @path="/deja-set-development/_search", @query=#<Tire::Search::Query:0x007f88ab915088 @value={:query_string=>{:query=>"oh"}}>, @facets={"type"=>{:terms=>{:field=>:_type, :size=>10, :all_terms=>false}}}>
```

Here is where I call will_paginate:

```
= will_paginate @search_results.results, params
```

Here is where I iterate through the results

```
@search_results.results.each
```

Does anyone have any thoughts?

Edit ---

I'm not sure what is going on, but I did this and it is working.

```
@search_results = @search_results.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 5)
```

Comment: How are you doing the actual search?

Comment: @search_results = Tire.search(INDEX_NAME, load: true, page: (params[:page] || 1), per_page: 2 ) do

Comment: Please edit your _question_ and add this information to it. Also, please use the code formatting for better readability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to clarify, I've attached my github correspondence with @karmi here.

https://github.com/karmi/tire/issues/627#issuecomment-13449368

I was using Tire.search as opposed to searching by model. As @karmi notes, at the moment :per_page and :page are not supported with Tire.

Here is how I solved this:

```
    @search_results = Tire.search [:index1, :index2, :index3], :load => true, :from => from, :size => size  do
        query do
            string q, :default_operator => 'AND', :fields => [:name1, :name2]
        end
    end
```

I ended up having to spin my own small pagination system to increment 'size' and 'from'. Here's the elasticsearch link on the topic.

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/search/from-size.html

You're able to still access

```
 = @search_results.results.total_entries/next_page/previous_page
```

which helps with pagination.

Thank you again @karmi.

Answer (score 1):

Please see the [integration test](https://github.com/karmi/tire/commit/09bab36) in Tire, and make sure you're passing all options properly.

Comment: Just to clarify, with multi_search page/per_page options aren't loaded correctly. Is this correct?